# What is "pseudo-future" in English grammar?

Tags: terminology

Searching Internet for pseudo-future with the reference to English grammar did not yield any meaningful result. Is pseudo-future a term referring to subjunctive mood or future-in-the-past?

Comment: If you can't find any reference to it on the Internet, *pseudo-future* is probably not a generally accepted name.

Comment: sounds like a post-modern(!) quantum reality synonym

Comment: It's grammar with a soft fuzzy finish.

Comment: Where do you see this term? Does your English teacher use it? Did you see it in a textbook or grammar?

Comment: https://books.google.com/books?id=b4Hhp5R5aJkC&pg=PA807&lpg=PA807&dq=pseudo-future+grammar&source=bl&ots=Ufn2zRU58o&sig=2TOBvpbhZ4m0TExdy2T4Gb9EdL4&hl=ja&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiftO61pNLTAhWmjlQKHZMeBJEQ6AEIYzAK#v=onepage&q=pseudo%20future%20tense&f=false

Comment: The term "pseudo-future" is encountered in several Japanese Grammar references, e.g. https://pomax.github.io/nrGrammar/. A similar term "Pseudo-t0-System" is used in [The Grammar of the English Tense System: A Comprehensive Analysis](https://books.google.com/books?id=b4Hhp5R5aJkC&pg=PA807&lpg=PA807&dq=pseudo-future+grammar&source=bl&ots=Ufn2zRU58o&)sig=2TOBvpbhZ4m0TExdy2T4Gb9EdL4&hl=ja&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiftO61pNLTAhWmjlQKHZMeBJEQ6AEIYzAK#v=onepage&q=pseudo%20future%20tense&f=false

Comment: In Japanese, the *pseudo-future* seems to be an alternative name for the [*volitional*](http://selftaughtjapanese.com/2015/02/17/the-japanese-volitional-form-%E3%81%97%E3%82%88%E3%81%86%E3%80%81%E3%80%9C%E3%81%97%E3%81%BE%E3%81%97%E3%82%87%E3%81%86-more-than-just-lets/) tense. English doesn't have this tense. And it looks like you'd translate this Japanese tense into English using four or five different constructions, depending on exactly what it was being used for.

Comment: First of all, volitional form of a verb is not a tense. Second, Japanese textbooks confuse term "volitional" with cohortative. Finally, "want to or has a will do something" is a volitional construction in English. Japanese does not have "pseudo-future" - it is an English phrase that describe a special irrealis mood. Some grammarians argue that "irrealis" is an incorrect form either.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably referring to the future tense in English,  or, more accurately, the lack of a future tense. This deficiency leads to implying tense through the use of auxillary verbs such as

- *will* (and *won't* and *shall*): *I will be home tomorrow.*
- *going to*:  *I am going to sing after dinner.*
- forms of *be*: *You are singing after me.*

Also,the simple present may be used, for example:
 - *I sing after dinner.*

It's easy to see how more than one method might be used to convey the same meaning about a future occurence.

So, without having a true future tense, one might refer to these alternative steps as the **pseudo-future**.

As mentioned in other comments, this is not a common expression, but its reasonable to assume this is its meaning.

Comment: You could make it clearer that this answer is an educated guess.